# Upload FIle In Blazor WebAssembly hosted by aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, blazor-webassembly

I tried to upload an image in Blazor wasm.
It hasn't any error, but the file didn't upload to wwwroot/images directory,

The code I use for upload is here:

```
byte[] ImageUploaded ; // I have got bytes of file by a code before.
if (ImageUploaded != null)
{
     string path = "~/images";
     if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
     path = Path.Combine(path, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(fileName));
     await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, ImageUploaded);
}
```

Can you resolve this problem?

I have searched the web and this site, But I haven't found any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because My Project is a BlazorWebAssembly hosted by AspnetCore
[(See Image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2djUj.png)
then, I uploaded the file in server side (api controller):

```
    private async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(AppUser user)
{
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    path = Path.Combine(path, @"../Client/wwwroot/images");
    if (Directory.Exists(path) == false) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    path = Path.Combine(path, user.ImageName);
    if (user.UserImage != null)
    {
        try
        {
            await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, user.UserImage);
            return Ok("Succeded");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return NotFound(ex.Message);
        }
    }
        return null;

}
```

AppUser is a class that contains two property related to Image:
public byte[] UserImage {get;set;}
public string UserImage  {get;set;}

It's working correctly, But you may suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#upload-files-to-a-server) to compose the file upload feature, and since you want to save file in `wwwroot` folder, you can change the path in the save file method like below(I created wwwroot/files folder), and you can see my test result.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\files", fileName);
await using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Create);
await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
```

[image]

Comment: This solution didn't work, BUT I changed the root path to "../client/wwwroot/images", so it worked correctly.
I should mention that my project is a blazor Wasm hosted by aspnet, then, the solution has 3 projects: Client, Server and Shared.

Comment: yes, I also test in a hosted blazor web assemebly project. and the official document I shared is also based on this kind of project. Anyway it's good that your code worked.